# Python odict: reordering keys

Tags: python

I'd like to reorder keys in Python odict (not 2.7 OrderedDict).

https://github.com/bluedynamics/odict

How I could implement moveAfter() and moveBefore() functions, so I could shuffle the keys around? Do any similar helper functions already exist through some Python magic?

Comment: Are you sure a dictionary best represents your intention here? This sounds like a better candidate for a `list`

Comment: There is a reason why it is called **ordered** dictionary...

Comment: A quick scan of the [source code](https://github.com/bluedynamics/odict/blob/master/src/odict/pyodict.py) shows that it uses a doubly linked list; reordering would have to traverse that list and rework that list. Not an easy task, I fear.

Comment: @Eric: ordered dicts have their place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Absolutely, but I'd argue that once you need to reorder your dictionary, you're onto a loser

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ordered dicts do have their place, but 90% of the time when people are having problems with them, it turns out the ordered dict was blatantly unnecessary…

Comment: Meanwhile, is there a good reason you can't use an `OrderedDict` instead (which is much easier to re-order), or some other implementation (it's pretty easy to write one yourself)? Or, alternatively, would it be acceptable to create a new `odict` in your new order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reordering behavior is implemented here:

https://github.com/bluedynamics/node/blob/master/src/node/behaviors/order.py#L11

The business logic acts on the underlying odict data structure.
It has been planned for a while to move aquivalent code upstream to odict.